# Assertion Advance Specification

Tags: java, selenium, testng, assert, assertions

```
public class openbowser {

    public WebDriver driver= null;
    String browser="mozilla";
    String url="https://www.google.com";
    String actualTitle = driver.getTitle(); 
    String expectedTitle = "googleInd"; 
    assert.assertTrue(actualTitle,expectedTitle); 
    Reporter.log("Application Launched successfully ");  
}
```

When I run the Test, it fails and will show the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [googleInd] but found [Google]
```

Is there any method I can modify the assertion? It should mention details in more plain english.

Example:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected title "googleInd" but found "Google"
```

Comment: The source code is syntactically incorrect. You have method calls outside of a method body (`assert.assertTrue(...)` and `Reporter.log(...)`). Also, please respect Java naming conventions: class names should always be written in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `assertEquals(String actual, String expected, String message)`

```
assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle, "Expected title '" + expectedTitle + "' but found '" + actualTitle + "'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Working for me now

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: Expected title 'googleInd' but found 'Google' expected [googleInd] but found [Google]...                 So its duplicate the same assertion error... Any better idea to eliminate the duplication ?

Comment: @user4986774 The second one is the message. You can put there whatever you want or nothing at all. Just don't put any message.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. If you look into the signature of **assertTrue** it is defined as :

```
void org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(boolean condition)
Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't, an AssertionError is thrown.

Parameters:
condition the condition to evaluate
```

So when we invoke **assertTrue** we have to keep the input parameter as a **boolean**. To achieve that instead of passing two `String` literals as follows :

```
assert.assertTrue(actualTitle,expectedTitle);
```

We will pass the **boolean** parameter as follows :

```
public WebDriver driver= null;
String browser="mozilla";
String url="https://www.google.com";
String actualTitle = driver.getTitle(); 
String expectedTitle = "googleInd"; 
Assert.assertTrue(expectedTitle.contains(actualTitle), "Expected title " + expectedTitle +" but found "+ actualTitle);
Reporter.log("Application Launched successfully ");
```

Comment: Your suggestion is good , but still shows               
 java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]..
or 
 java.lang.AssertionError: expected [googleInd] but found [Google]        
      My questions is  different as mentioned earlier
    
    is there any method I can modify the assertion? Example ... It should mention details in more plain English  
    
    ----- java.lang.AssertionError: Expected title " googleInd " but found " Google "   --------